# Convert foreach to Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I need convert `foreach` to `Parallel.foreach` , anyone can help me ?

```
    foreach (DataRow row2 in DT.Rows)
    {
       try 
       {
           bool check = (urlcheck(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
           if (check == true)
              ExecuteQuery("");
           else
              ExecuteQuery("");
       }
       catch{ }
       i++;
     }
```

Comment: why you want to convert to Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: `i = i++;` very interesting piece of code

Comment: You aren't even using `row2` inside of the foreach. Are you sure you even need a loop or was this originally a `for` loop?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Not only that `if (check == true)ExecuteQuery("");
     else ExecuteQuery("");` also very interesting

Comment: @DGibbs maybe it is being used withing `ExecuteQuery`

Comment: You should write `i = i++;` simple as `i++;` . . . its incrementing `i` only

Comment: @SriramSakthivel agree, but probably OP just doesn't want to show the contents of `ExecuteQuery` calls. Not sure about it, just playing devil's advocate

Comment: Is `ExecuteQuery` thread-safe? If not, parallelizing this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an overload of the `Parallel.ForEach` so your `i` parameter is provided by the foreach method:

```
Parallel.ForEach(DT.Rows.OfType<System.Data.DataRow>(), (DataRow row2, ParallelLoopState loopState, long i) =>
{
    try {
        bool check = (urlcheck(dataGridView.Rows[(int)i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
        if (check == true)
            ExecuteQuery("");
        else
            ExecuteQuery("");
    }
    catch{ }
});
```

For the `OfType<>` method you need to add `using System.Linq` to your using statements.

Now the index (`i`) is automaticly assigned by the method call so you don't have to worry about thread safety of `i`.

Comment: Error1:The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @MrKazemi changed so the type arguments are clear. Does this give you an error?

Comment: @MrKazemi my bad. I typed `DT` instead of `DT.Rows` please try it again.

Comment: Error1:The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<System.Data.DataRow>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>, System.Action<System.Data.DataRow>)' has some invalid arguments 
Error2:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'           Error3Argument 2: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Action<System.Data.DataRow>'

Comment: @MrKazemi Another edit. Dont forget to add the using statement.

Comment: Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int'

Comment: @MrKazemi added an int cast. Please try again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Parallel.ForEach(DT.Rows, row2 => {
    try
    {
        bool check = (urlcheck(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
        if (check == true)
            ExecuteQuery("");
        else
            ExecuteQuery("");
    }
    catch { }
    i = i++; 
});
```

Keep in mind: `i = i++;` outside thread could be dangroous if used in wrong way. (btw: strange assigment)

Comment: Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach(DT.Rows ... gives an error that the arguments can't be inferred from the usage, thus the answer as presented will not compile. You need to use DT.AsEnumerable() and add the reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions.

Answer (score -2):

```
Parallel.ForEach(DT.Rows, Row =>
{
  try
  {
    bool check = (urlcheck(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
    if (check == true)
        ExecuteQuery("");
    else
        ExecuteQuery("");
  }
  catch() {}
  i = i++;
});
```

Comment: You should really use camel casing for variables in C#.

Comment: Incrementing `i` like that from multiple threads would not work.

Comment: I my compnay project i am follow camel casing for variable name

Comment: It's depend how we use the value of i. If we want to check how many thread finished execution then we get it by i value.

Comment: Error1:A class type expected

Comment: Your lambda variable `Row` is using pascal casing in your example.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would help if you put some effort into explaining your answer better.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach(DT.Rows ... gives an error that the arguments can't be inferred from the usage, thus the answer as presented will not compile. You need to use DT.AsEnumerable() and add the reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions.